# why doesn't it find the class when it finds the script?

Tags: php, namespaces

There is some weird thing going on.

Following is a snippet from `view_reminders.php` :

```
<?php 
  namespace reminder;
  require_once('./reusable/reminders.php');
?>

some HTML...

<?php  
    $reminders = new Reminders(); # STATEMENT THAT THROWS AN ERROR : LINE 23
    $reminder_details = $reminders->get_reminders();
    foreach($reminder_details as $reminder) {
        echo $reminder;
    }
?>
```

In the above script , the statement `$reminders = new Reminders()` throws an error : `Fatal error: Class 'reminder\Reminders' not found in E:\Installed_Apps\xampp\htdocs\remind\view_reminders.php on line 23`.

I do not understand this error. Following is the snippet from `reminders.php` :

```
<?php
namespace reminder;
namespace connection;
require_once('./reusable/connection.php');

Class Reminders{
    private $user_info;
    private $userID;
    private $reminder_info;
    private $reminder_count;

            .
            .
            .
    }
```

Now why doesn't it find the class `Reminders` when it finds the script `reminders.php` ?

*Note: The directory structure :*

```
     +--->resuable
          +---->connection.php
           ---->reminders.php
     ---->view_reminders.php
```

`view_reminders.php` is just outside `connection.php` and `reminders.php` that are inside the `reusable` directory.

Comment: I don't think you can have two namespace declarations in PHP. So class `Reminder` is in fact in `connection` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your namespace to `connection`. You can use [multiple namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php), but you would have to write it like:

```
<?php
namespace connection;
require_once('./reusable/connection.php');

namespace reminder;
Class Reminders{
    private $user_info;
    private $userID;
    private $reminder_info;
    private $reminder_count;

            .
            .
            .
    }
```

Also check the link to the manual for the recommended way to use multiple namespaces using brackets:

```
<?php
namespace connection {
require_once('./reusable/connection.php');
}

namespace reminder {
Class Reminders{
    private $user_info;
    private $userID;
    private $reminder_info;
    private $reminder_count;

            .
            .
            .
    }
}
```

Comment: That's okay. But how am I going to use the class that is there in the `connection` namespace.? Class `Reminders` makes use of `connection` namespace.

Comment: @SuhailGupta I'm not sure what you mean, you can access your Connection class (I assume it is something like that) with `connection\Connection`.

Answer (score 0):

Double namespace on Reminders class?

Answer (score 0):

Can you really use two namespaces that way??.. as i know, in this code:

```
namespace reminder;
namespace connection;
```

next code will go for connection namespace, and reminder is empty

try to remove connection namespace from there.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP: Defining multiple namespaces in the same file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php) :

> Multiple namespaces may also be declared in the same file.

In "reminders.php", you've declared multiple namespaces as per the syntax described on that page.  I'd suggest the latter one (`connection`) is the namespace under which your `Reminders` class has been created.